# How does the compiler internally differentiate between pointers and normal variables?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int a=10;
int *p=&a;
```

Okay, here, p points to a; p also has a address, and in that address, the address of a is stored(if I'm right).

So a:(some address): 10
p:(some address):address of a

Now i know how pointers work; I just want to know compilers differentiate between pointers and normal variables? (seems like a dumb question, but yes)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague to me. Could you add a concrete example that shows a case where the compiler "differentiates"? Or where you think this happens?

Comment: the compiler keeps track of what you told it, you told it a contains a number and p contains a pointer . IN fact you asked it to make a thing called a that is a number and a thing called p that holds a pointer to number

Comment: You declared `a` as an `int` and `p` as a pointer to `int`. That's how the compiler knows. I don't understand what you're asking. And I'm not so sure you do know how pointers work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just a matter of data type. `int*` is a different type than `int` other than that I think they are just like any other variable. Like how the complier differentiates between `char` and `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In the compile-time, the compiler takes note of variable declarations and looks for the data types of the variables defined. Therefore, after seeing the declaration

```
int a = 10;
int* p = &a;
```

compiler knows the data types of the variables (but still unaware of the values).

In the run-time, the compiler need to allocate memory(which obviously not same for 'int' and 'int*') to the variables so that the values can be stored. Hence, compiler should know the data types.

In the same way compiler works with different data types.